# Render rows of arbitrary length with a cursor

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have a helper like so:

```
// returns all cards from this deck
cards: function () {
  return Cards.find({
    _id: { $in: this.parentComponent().currentData().deck }
  });
}
```

I want to render rows of arbitrary length. Eg, it might look like this

```
each rows size=5
  .row
    each rowCards
      div(class="col col-{{columnSize}}")
        | Card position {{ @index }}
        +Card.description
```

The problem with immediately breaking it into rows is that it does not maintain the `@index`, which I will need on the iteration.

Is there a way to create rows for a cursor in meteor?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding the problem, but this feels like a case where using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and not replying on a predefined row number may be a better solution.